# Dimensional analysis of Laplacian

Tags: laplacian, dimensional-analysis

Given a function $$f(x, y): \mathbb{R} \left[kg \right] \times \mathbb{R} \left[K \right] \mapsto \mathbb{R} \left[m \right]$$ where the units of the variables $x, y$ and of the function $f(x, y)$ are written in [square brackets], what are the units of the Laplacian $\Delta f(x,y)$? If the Laplacian of the function $f(x,y)$ is to be computed as

$$
\Delta f(x,y) = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(x,y) + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(x,y)
$$

then the units of the Laplacian would be $m\cdot kg^{-2} + m\cdot K^{-2}$, which does not make sense to me from the perspective of dimensional analysis, since you cannot add two numbers which represent different physical quantities into a single number.

Is Laplacian defined **only** for such functions of multiple variables, where each variable represents the same physical quantity (and of course for functions of single variable)?

---

**Edit:**

Given the comments below, computing the Laplacian does indeed make "physical" sense only if the domain of the function consists of variables of the same physical units.

However, does there exist a practical (non-toy) example where we compute the Laplacian of a function despite the physical units of the input variables differ and the result has real-world usage?

Comment: The Laplacian is of course defined for any function of $2$ variables, but you're correct that it's only "physically meaningful" when each variable has the same units.

Comment: I agree, Laplacian is for the case where $x$ and $y$ are in the same units.  In fact, we probably want the case where "rotation" in the coordinate system $(x,y)$ makes sense.

Comment: Physically, the Laplacian only makes sense on an "isotropic" space. It measures the deviation of $f$ at a point from its average over a small sphere around that point. As a result it is rotationally invariant and there is no way of conceiving rotations or the concept of a sphere in a space where one dimension has $\mathrm{kg}$ units and the other has $\mathrm{m}$ units without some arbitrary conversion factor between the two.